# IE 11 doesn't display all my html output from server

Tags: html, internet-explorer, display

I create a method on sever side which echo a html page. 
The page contains mainly the content of a xml file and each xml element is in a div. 
I wanted see to the result according to my xml file size.

For 20Mega (size of file size), 
On IE9, all the html was displayed. 
[display on IE9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssz2x.png).
But on IE11, there are some gaps at the end of the page, all the content is not displayed.
[display on IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdOgx.png).
On Chrome also, all the content is displayed. 
Can anyone tell me if there is size of the html to print ? or explain why difference of display between IE9 and IE11 and how to fix it.

Thanks :)

There is my code :

Comment: Make sure angle brackets are escaped by replacing those with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. To output HTML or XML code as text, always escape special characters with a function like PHP’s [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: I did. That's why the output is quite good on IE9

Comment: You should provide a minimal code example (not just resulting screenshots) for more certainty.

Comment: How can I attached files ?

Comment: An established way to provide working demos at Stack Overflow is using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).